# INSERT statement conflicted with COLUMN FOREIGN KEY

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a FK in my table that looks like this:

[image: FK]

Clearly, I should be able to insert `NULL` into this column as well as any value that exists in the parent table.

But when I try to insert `NULL`, I get the following error:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "users_fk". The conflict occurred in database "mydatabase", table
>   "dbo.country", column 'country_id'.

Comment: can you script the table and post it?

Comment: Should I paste the CREATE SCRIPT of my table here? Would that help?
@Chopin Which table do you want to see? users or country?

Comment: @marc_s in my insert query, I haven't mentioned all the fields except the country_id field. That means it would insert NULL into this field, right?

Comment: @Siva Then how do you think I can debug this issue? Any ideas?

Comment: Edit your question and paste the CREATE TABLE for both. I would like to see what constraints they have.

Comment: As well as the INSERT statement...

Comment: If you're not specifying the column in the `INSERT` statement - then maybe an invalid **default value** is defined on that column?? Something like a default of 0 or something. If you have a default value - that value will be inserted

Comment: @marc_s Yes you are right. It was default to zero.
Please reply this as a comment so I can accept as an answer and close this thread. Thanks marc_s and all others for helping me fix this problem.

Comment: @mohsensajjadi please read my last comment. The problem is fixed. The problem was with the default value of the column.
Thanks for trying to help me :)

Comment: @marc_s can you please add your comment as an answer? I want to give you points.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are absolutely right - you should be able to insert `NULL` into this column.

Are you **500% sure** that you are? The error message says something else - it appears as if you're inserting an invalid value.

Could it be that you have

(a) another line in your script that inserts additional (invalid) values?

Or

(b) do you happen to have a trigger on this table that does something invalid?

**Update:** (based on your comment)
If you're **not** specifying the column in the `INSERT` statement - then maybe an invalid **default value** is defined on that column? Something like a default of `0` or something.

If you do have a default value - that default value will be inserted (and not `NULL`, as you seem to be expecting)

Comment: Thanks. I had to remove the default value to fix it.

Comment: I had a GUID and it was becoming a 000-0000-000-000 something. I had to make it nullable GUID.

Comment: I was 100% sure I had a null until I actually checked and the nullable int was in fact 0.